# Bytes and String Conversion [Checksum]

Tags: java, string, udp, arrays, checksum

I have a file that I need to transmit through UDP reliably (I know TCP is the better option). Hence, I require a checksum to verify the data consistency.

At the sender, I have formatted the packet with this code:

```
static class Generator {

    public static byte[] format(String type, int sequence_no, byte[] data) {

        String header = type + "|" + sequence_no + "|" + Validator.getChecksum(data) + "|";
        String temp = new String(data, 0, data.length); 
        String combine = header + temp;

        return combine.getBytes();
    }
}
```

This would return me the final byte of data that would be sent over.

```
static class Validator {

    public static String getChecksum(byte[] bytes) {
        CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
        crc.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        return crc.getValue() + "";
    }
  }
```

The BufferedFileReader would read the data into the byte array which will be sent to this Generate.format method to attach the appropriate header info.

However, at my receiver's end, I can't seem to be getting back the same amount of bytes, although the data 'looks the same'

```
  String raw = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
  String[] split = raw.split("\\|");
  System.out.println(split[3].getBytes().length);
```

I am suspecting that the bytes that in the buffer are not fully equivalent to the string received resulting in the receiver getting a different output.

Can someone spot something wrong?

Comment: Does the data as a `String` contain the character `'|'` that you're trying to split with?

Comment: Could you post your output and what output you expect?

Comment: @Bubletan Yes, I have used '|' as a delimiter. The code works for normal String data however, when the data is in the form of bytes, it doesn't work

Comment: @Verim The outputs are in illegible �="$&)+.136 form like this.. I am trying to ensure that the data transmitted (eg. length 950) when transmitted, will also be (length 950) when received. However, the byte length seems to change.

Comment: You know that sending data can split and merge these data. Means for one send() you 'can' get multiple receive() on the other side and for multiple send() you 'can' get one receive(). So you have to split your received packages by yourself.

Comment: @toffee.beanns I mean, if the `String temp = new String(data, 0, data.length);` contains the character `'|'`, it won't split as intended.

Comment: Not to be negative here, but hopefully you found a less hacky way of doing this. UDP is stateless for a reason. Trying to do what you're (probably being forced into) doing is a terrible design because there are so many things that can go wrong which you're not accounting for, and which you could never properly and completely account for simply due to the fact that **UDP is unreliable**. Period. It's best uses are also it's biggest drawbacks for anything but media purposes.

Comment: If you're still in need of an answer, I believe the issue may be in the network between the sender and receiver. You may want to involve your system administrators and network people to inspect the packets while they're in transit.